# How to get id of a view that opened a DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

I add a onClick method to various EditTexts. It opens a DialogFragment.

---

```
public void eligeHora (View view){
        TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"hadshads");
    }
```

---

Now, inside the DialogFragment class I want to get the id of THE EditText clicked (there are many). In this example I get the EditText with the id "hora", but I want it "generic".

---

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        //Create and return a new instance of TimePickerDialog
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, 0, 0,
                true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
//Do something with the user chosen time
        //Get reference of host activity (XML Layout File) TextView widget
        EditText tv =  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.hora);

        tv.setText(String.valueOf(hourOfDay)+ " : " +
                String.valueOf(minute) + "\n");
    }

}
```

---

How do I get the id of the view clicked to open the DialogFragment? In the example I used the id of a specific view (*R.id.hora*), but I want to be able to use this fragment with all the views that have the method *eligeHora*.

Comment: what you want ?

Comment: Get the id of the view that opened the DialogFragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the id to the `Fragment` not via the Constructor but by using a static method:

```
public static TimePickerFragment instance(int viewId){
    TimePickerFragment fragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("KEY_ID", viewId);
    fragment.setArguments(b);
    return fragment;
}
```

Instead of

> ```
> TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
> ```

you'd have to write

```
 TimePickerFragment newFragment = TimePickerFragment.instance(myEditTextID);
```

Later on, you can retrieve the id like this:

```
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    int id = getArguments().getInt("KEY_ID");
    //...
}
```

But be aware that it's not a good idea to access `View`s ´from within the `Fragment` which are not part of the `Fragment`. Consider using an interface to communicate with the `Activity`

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is basically correct: you can pass the view id to the `TimePickerFragment` by using `setArguments()`. The only piece it is missing is how to actually get the id of the view that was clicked on.

Assuming that you're using the `android:onClick` attribute on all of your views, and each of them uses your `eligeHora(View view)` method...

The `View` parameter to this method is the view the user clicked on. So you can get the clicked view's id by calling `view.getId()` inside `eligeHora()`.